# How to add google as a AWS cognito identity provider in AWS CloudFormation template in JSON

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito

I'm using amazon web services. In the AWS CloudFormation I'm creating a template in JSON where I have to add Identity Pool as a resource where I have to use Google as Cognito Identity Provider.
If we use Google as in CognitoIdentityProvider then what should be the value in the  object ? i.e

```
"CognitoIdentityProvider":[
{
  "ClientId": String,
  "ProviderName": String,
  "ServerSideTokenCheck": Boolean
}
]
```

Can anyone help me with the values of this object properties if we use Google as an CognitoIdentityProvider ?
Please help.

Comment: Hope this links helps : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/simplify-web-identity-federation-setup-with-aws-cloudformation/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I setup AWS Cognito User Pool Identity Providers with Cloudformation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49395669/can-i-setup-aws-cognito-user-pool-identity-providers-with-cloudformation)

Answer (score 6):

Bit related to [Can I setup AWS Cognito User Pool Identity Providers with Cloudformation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49395669/can-i-setup-aws-cognito-user-pool-identity-providers-with-cloudformation/58634132#58634132)

As I said there, what worked for me is something like:

```
CognitoUserPoolIdentityProvider:
  Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolIdentityProvider
  Properties: 
    ProviderName: Google
    AttributeMapping:
      email: emailAddress
    ProviderDetails:
      client_id: <yourclientid>.apps.googleusercontent.com
      client_secret: <yourclientsecret>
      authorize_scopes: email openid
    ProviderType: Google
    UserPoolId: 
      Ref: CognitoUserPool
```